# Limit voting with cookie for multiple content on same page

Tags: php, cookies

I have set of content on website's home page just like reddit and I have no user registration feature on the website. I'm not planing to get one. My goal is to limit people voting more then one for same content. I'm planing to check this with IP on the database and cookie. I have a problem with the cookies...

here is my code

```
  <?php
    $ContentID = intval( $_POST['id'] );

    $uniqueID = 'Ju?hG&F0yh9?=/6*GVfd-d8u6f86hp'.$ContentID;
    setcookie ('voter', $uniqueID,time()+3600*24, '/', DOMAIN);


    if ( $_COOKIE['voter'] == $uniqueID ) {
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>'false', 'message'=>'Just one for same post.'));  
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>'false', 'message'=>'voted'));
    }
  ?>
```

Problem here is that it limits for only one content but I'm able to vote other contents. How can I prevent this happening?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will actually set a cookie named `voter` for only the given content-id. voting on another post will work, but the old information will be removed.

If you are using a database and don't want to let users register, you can just store IP-POST_ID pairs and check on the server-side. At that point there is no need to do anything with cookies except for storing preferences or something.

As you are (or maybe not) aware, this also means that only one user from a given IP can vote, meaning corporate networks etc will most like be seen as one single user, even if there are hundreds of people working (and possibly voting).

Comment: so, it is not possible without user registration?

Comment: It's possible, but with this downside. Another option would be to set a cookie (with unlimited lifetime) with an ID for each user, and store that cookie inside the database. In that case, it doesn't matter on which IP the user is, but as a downside: when a user clears the cookies it means they can vote again.